Using VeriFIX by itiviti for Stock Exchanges
Does anyone have a guide book or anything that might help with learning how to use VeriFIX by itiviti for exchanges? It seems the parent company no longer supports it and they changed their name to Broadridge.
Thank you.
I am having difficulties connecting to Replay and Snapshot Market Data Gateways and I have no specs files to help me with configuring the connections and messages, was only able to successfully connect and receive real-time feed for both ITCH and FAST protocols, also no one is helping or is knowledgeable where I'm from.
